# System.Text.Json randomly fails to serialize & Deserialize if the source code generator is active

Tags: c#, serialization

Hello I am working on a game with a database of complex nested Objects.
We are on FNA framework (C#), No Unity.

We try to move from NewtonSoft to System.Text.Json since the game will run in a Native AOT environment.

System.Text.Json "randomly" fails to serialize/Deserialize all the properties of object  some objects are correct, some others not when we activate the source code generator.

When the source code generator is disabled, it serialize/deserialize properly (but not working on AOT).

This is our serialization option on Newton (always working even slowly on Native AOT)

```cs
       public static JsonSerializerSettings settings  = new JsonSerializerSettings
                       {
                           Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
                           TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                           DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate,
                           NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                           ObjectCreationHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,

                       Error = (sender, args) =>
                           {
                               args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                               Console.WriteLine("JsonDeserialize Error: ***" + args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);

                           }

       };
```

There are our serialization options for system.Text.Json

```cs
  public static JsonSerializerOptions jbinSerializerOption = new JsonSerializerOptions
  {

      
        WriteIndented = false, // Keep this as false to reduce JSON size.
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false,
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault, // Ignore default values to reduce JSON size.
       IncludeFields = true,
       ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
       TypeInfoResolver = Core_JsonContext.Default, //When we mask this, source code is disabled

  };
```

and there is the source code generator class.

```cs
 [JsonSourceGenerationOptions(  //wouafo ::: Source Generator parameter here
     WriteIndented = false,
     PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
     GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Default,
     DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault,
     IncludeFields = true
     )]
 
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Data_Zone))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Data_PageCredit))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(AstralDBSystemLoader))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(AstralDataBaseLoader))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector3))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector4))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_Bitmap))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_Sprite))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_Sequence))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_Clip))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_ClipEtatMouv))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_ClipImgCle))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_ClipRoute))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_ClipImgCleAction))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_IANeurone))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Data_Zone))]
 [JsonSerializable(typeof(CoreBD.Core_ParamZone))]

 public  partial class Core_JsonContext : JsonSerializerContext //wouafo ::: Source Generator est ici
 {
    
 }
```

Do you see something We did bad?
when we try to use a simple cloning like

```cs
 string copieText = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(source, jbinSerializerOptionTriche);
 return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(copieText, jbinSerializerOption);
```

with source code Generator we get null Object or incomplete object.

The weird part is that if we serialize our database in a file with no source code, we can get it back after with source code. But we need to clone during runtime that's where it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related at all, but this particular line seems suspicious:

```
PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false,
```

By default, Newtonsoft Json is case **insenstitive**. When you migrate to System.Text.Json you'd normally explicitly set

```
PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = **true**
```

to make sure you can still read in the values if somewhere in your system it makes a round-trip where the properties change case.

Comment: I tried and since some bad coders had the great ideas to name some private property "scale" and the public getter/setter "Scale" there was a lot of errors due to confusing field names.